# PowerShell Desired State Configuration - Conditionally Create resources

Tags: dsc

What I am trying to do is the following. Our server host 4 different web applications through an IIS Website ( maybe more in the future ) .  Depending on the customer they may have 1 or more of those 4 IIS Sites that needs to be added to the server depending on the services we sell them ( plus all the configuration for it).   All IIS site application configuration is the same regardless of the customer  which is why I want to use Desired State Configuration to keep it consistent + easy to update hundreds of servers

I am trying to compile these scripts from a central pull server and not the actual machine.  With the number of servers we are managing central administration is important.

What I am trying to do is to figure out is the way to add the logic to the script so that we can only install what is needed for each customer.   I gather I need to add this to ConfigurationData file and call it when the script compiles and it generates a separate MOF file

Would it look something like this where for Server1 it would install the IIS site for Application1 and Application 3 and for Server 2 it would install the site for Application2.

```
$ConfigData = @{
    AllNodes = @(
        @{
            NodeName = 'Server1'
            Application1 = $true
            Application2 = $false
            Application3 = $true
            Application4 = $false

        },
        @{
            NodeName = 'Server2'
            Application1 = $false
            Application2 = $true
            Application3 = $false
            Application4 = $false
        },
   )
}
```

How would the logic in the script look like?  Is there a better way to execute this?  First time I have really had to build this logic into state configuration?

Outside of that I have the state script written to do all the site configuration.  Just need to get over how to handle this logic.

Assistance with determining this logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
Configuration 'MyDscConfiguration'
{
    Node $AllNodes.NodeName
    {
        'declaration of features that always need to be present'
    }

    Node $AllNodes.Where{$_.Role -contains "Application1"}.NodeName
    {
        'Application1 configurations'
    }

    Node $AllNodes.Where{$_.Role -contains "Application2"}.NodeName
    {
        'Application2 configurations'
    }

    Node $AllNodes.Where{$_.Role -contains "Application3"}.NodeName
    {
        'Application3 configurations'
    }

    Node $AllNodes.Where{$_.Role -contains "Application4"}.NodeName
    {
        'Application4 configurations'
    }
}
```

and then to compile the different mof files you need to run:

```
$MyData =
@{
    AllNodes =
    @(
        @{
            NodeName    = 'Application1'
            Role = 'Application1'
        },

        @{
            NodeName    = 'Application12'
            Role = @('Application1', Application2)
        }
            
        ...
    )
}
    
MyDscConfiguration -ConfigurationData $MyData
```

If you want to know more about Separating configuration and environment data you can look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/configurations/separatingenvdata?view=dsc-1.1